# When reviewers vote to close for different reasons I want the real votes on the "closed" panel

Tags: feature-request

During the Close Votes Review there often exist two different approaches about **why** a question should be closed (I don't count "leave open" now).

At the end (after 5 votes to *close*) the majority reason "wins" - which is fine and sensible.

**But**: even if a reviewer voted for a different close reason (after careful deliberation) the panel beneath the question states all who voted to close as supporters of the chosen close reason.

While "*the majority wins*" is certainly ok (neither of us can be right at all times) I don't like "*the winner takes it all*" - there are cases where I *know*  (or at least believe) that the chosen close reason is wrong.

So the feature I am requesting is that dissenting close-voters should be mentioned with "their" close reason (or without any close reason at all).

Comment: I agree. And would even go 1 further: I believe that if there are more types of close votes the most informative one should prevail (since we are here to help people). To me a close vote with dupe should always win over other close votes (even if there are 4 off topic close votes).

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't think that is a good idea, I've seen lots of bad dupe votes.

Comment: That is an executional problem @seth ;) (expanding: why not let us vote to delete the bad dupe at the same time?)

Comment: I wanted to ask the *exact* same question!  [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/655381/black-and-grey-colored-bar) the *last vote* was "problem went away all by itself" **and is the only correct one!** 
So, where do we go with this?  Another [meta.se] question?